# Convergence to locally stable equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, nonlinear-dynamics

I am working with a system whose trajectories converge to the set of equilibria. I can characterize all the equilibria in a nice way and easily compute their stability and whether they are isolated or not. The dynamical system is described by a Lipschitz continuous vector field.

I conjecture that the system is "well behaved" so that the trajectories converge (almost always, depending on their initial condition) to the set of locally stable equilibria. I know that this is not always the case as there are plenty of counterexamples, e.g. this classic system with a homoclinic trajectory ([example](https://books.google.it/books?id=ht3rCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=%22shows%20that%20the%20properties%20unstable%20and%20attractive%20are%20not%20mutually%20exclusive%22&source=bl&ots=UsyHDkKFTa&sig=ACfU3U3ztTeQrm_Cie2XHfH7OI2M8tecLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAmJ6frND4AhXmR_EDHXFfDsQQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22shows%20that%20the%20properties%20unstable%20and%20attractive%20are%20not%20mutually%20exclusive%22&f=false)).

I am just wondering if there is any approach/result available in the literature to show that this is true, given certain conditions on the vector field.

Comment: are you talking about limit cycles? or more general type solutions e.g. unstable/stable saddle point pairs?

Comment: I am talking about a system for which I know the trajectories converge to equilibria. I already excluded limit cycles etc. I would like to know if there is any conditions on the vector field such that we can prove that convergence to the locally stable equilibria holds almost everywhere. Something of the type: consider a dynamical system with bounded trajectories whose trajectories always converge to some equilibrium of the system, under conditions xyz, almost all trajectories converge to a locally stable equilibrium. In other words, we can 'practically' ignore locally unstable equilibria.

Comment: Some conditions I am thinking of would be: excluding existence of homoclinic/heteroclinic orbits, but I don't really know where to start from.

Comment: So I am afraid I have not looked into this - outside the classic conditions for limit cycles, for my particular PhD case for homoclinic bifurcation limit cycles, where I also explored conditions on parameters for when the HC Limit cycle appears. One thing I was exploring was the extension of the saddle point eigenvectors as you know when trajectories will diverge and converge if interacting with an unstable node. So in short I am not aware, and I can't really help you here - but I will follow this post closely.

Comment: w.r.t your second comment - even with those orbits you get unstable trajectories based on initial conditions.

Comment: Yes, sure. For example in the simple (classic?) one-dimensional case $\dot{x}=x-x^3$, for all initial conditions except for the (measure zero) singleton $\{0\}$, the trajectories will converge to +1 or -1. How do we approach this problem (wherever possible) in higher dimensional systems for example?

Comment: my equation was $\ddot{x} - (x - c)\dot{x} -x + kx^2 = 0$ which has two fixed points. (this is actually the same example in Steven Strogatz "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" chapter 8 (I think)) - Like I said I have not had much luck - but there is a condition on the angle of the rotation of the saddle point with developing an orbit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137431/discussion-between-giangian-and-chinny84).